# Rank of certain elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

I need to calculate rank of the some
 elliptic curves,(espicially getting generators or finding a rational point
 on the elliptic curves) but I cannot do this by my computer.

> I am interested in calculating the rank of the following elliptic
>   curves.

The elliptic curve is
$$
 Y^2=X^3 - (3h^2)X^2 + 3h(h^3-h)X -(h^3-h)^2
$$

for $h=967, 1198, 1787, 1987$,

$h=2459, 2572, 2711, 2797, 2971, 4999$

please if possible find a generator for some of these elliptic curves.

Comment: try https://cloud.sagemath.com/  ([examples](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/constructions/elliptic_curves.html))

Comment: The standard Sage implementation relies on Cremona's mwrank, and mwrank "searches" for appropriate two-covers, rather than directly computing them. I think Magma is better for things like this, and the [online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) may handle most of the OP's cases.

Answer (score 3):

The following results were found using a mixture of my own codes and Denis Simon's excellent ellrank code.

The curves have trivial torsion so Mwrank might take a long time - I haven't tried. The two heights for the rank 1 curves are for the two possible height normalisations.

h=967 Rank=1 generator=[238501273696/245025, 900632541139856/121287375]

h=1198 Rank=0

h=1787 Rank=0 or 2

h=1987 Rank=0 or 2

h=2459 Rank=1  Height=37.4/74.8

h=2572 Rank=2 generators= [60035809/9, 302757191/27] and [3435573760731933430513/381659437643236, 27488556048550361767336062809879/7456139229698648679016]

h=2711 Rank =0

h=2797 Rank=1 Height=28.1/56.2

h=2971 Rank=0

h=4999 Rank=1 Height=29.7/59.4

If I get peace from my grandchildren I might try the three rank 1 curves!!

Comment: What that means rank 0 OR 2 ?

Comment: Means that the rank is even and 0<=rank<=2, based on output from ellrank.

Comment: . . . and assuming the parity conjecture.  Presumably conductor much too large for Heegner-point constructions in the rank-1 cases.

Comment: ِDear Prof Allan Mac Leod;

Comment: ِDear Prof Allan Mac Leod; Thank you very so much for your times and your reply and your support..Thank you..I am very glad for  these results; Please, if possible, writte the generetors  for each case that rank is positive. Please ,if possible, find the generators of the other elliptic curves for me..I need generators of these elliptic curves when rank is positive.. Thank you so much for your times ..sincerely yours.mehdi baghalaghdam

Comment: I wolud like to thank Professor Allan Mac Leod, Known Mathematician, for so much help me. Thank you so much for your times..These results were gereat......sincerley yours.... mehdi  baghalaghdam.

Comment: Dear Prof Noam D. Elkies; Thank you very much for your useful comments. sincerely yours; mehdi baghalaghdam

Answer (score 1):

The following finish off the results:

(a) h = 2459

x = 2455940168334175449299068876662469864/403764781843031846693075441721

Conductor = 329061105621720

(b) h = 2797

x = 18256234369/2304

Conductor = 550823321110248

(c) h = 4999

x = 38932053386017900293094583125/1502165941669975655844

Conductor = 401464366065

By the way, if you set $x=z+h^2$ the curve reduces to the very simple Weierstrass form
\begin{equation*}
y^2=z^3-3h^2z-h^2(h^2+1)
\end{equation*}

Comment: Dear Prof Allan Mac Leod:

Comment: I wolud like to thank Professor Allan Mac Leod, Known Mathematician, for so much help me. Thank you so much for your times..These results were gereat......sincerley yours.... mehdi  baghalaghdam.

Comment: I would like to thank Prof Allan Mac Leod  for useful helps in my paper....thank you  ..sincerely.yours

Comment: Dear Prof Allan Mac leod.The solutions given for the x-coorditane s are the generators   x-coorditanes  for elliptic curves, Is it right?

Comment: Dear Prof Allan Mac Leod. I wish to know  how  to get Denis Simon'  ellrank code for caculating rank of elliptic curves  with the coefficients large? Thank you for your giude.

Comment: Are there any  powerful anline progrem for caculating rank of the elliptic curves with large coefficients? I need to calculate rank of the some other elliptic curves with large coefficients. I use sagemath progrem but it is very slow.please introduce a powerful  anline progrem for me. thank you for your support and your times..